# How to load image in Picasso AFTER it's downloaded from asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, picasso

I've got some code which firsts downloads an image in asynctask and then loads it into my imageview after. But when I execute the following code, Picasso says that the image doesn't exist because asynctask hasn't downloaded it yet.
 it but when i do

```
download.execute()
mpicasso.load()
```

I tried putting Picasso load onPostExecute but then it doesn't compile. Any suggestions?

Comment: Like you said, you need a listener for when the image is loaded, then do things after you get the event that it has finished loading. You should pass a reference of the parent to the asynctask, then call the parent from asynctask to load the image, since only asynctask knows when it has finished loading. I hope this makes sense as it's pretty confusing without a nice class diagram explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to download it seperately. Picasso will manage it on its own -

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: But the thing is that i need to show somthing that image is downloading , becouse image has 4mb of size and it take a 10 second picasso to load it , and then u see nothing. And i tried to do this with async task with progress bar

Comment: And also i would need to download it every time then

Comment: Picasso will manage the image caching on its own, don't worry about this. Check this link for more details - http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Use placeholder to show loading image meanwhile Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)

Comment: Ok this work, thanks a lot :) i don't know how to give you a point... :/

Comment: Accept the answer, so that this will help others